# How to solve Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings issue

Tags: django, gdal

I am running on Windows 10 and have successfully installed the gdal 64 bit library from this resource:
https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

My django app is running with pipenv

I also added in my settings.py the variable : `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin'` and also add this variable also to the **path** variable ins system variables.

After every run of the development server i got the error :

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 121, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 208, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .features import DatabaseFeatures
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
  File "C:\Users\Maria\.virtualenvs\ev-loader-backend-7qq6TCvy\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 42, in <module>
    % '", "'.join(lib_names)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal204", "gdal203", "gdal202", "gdal201", "gdal20"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to go a bit further with the GDAL path. Try

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal300'
```

You may have to change the gdal300 part to whatever version of gdal you have. Also check to make sure that you are running 64bit Python. Otherwise you may have gotten the wrong osgeo4w version